# Making auto-complete field required and retrieving value in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using an remote auto-complete field from jquery mobile like explained here:
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/listview-autocomplete-remote/#&ui-state=dialog

2 such autocomplete fields are to be added in a form.
Please suggest how will I make auto-complete fields required.Basically how do I apply client side validation on this field.I am having problem in retrieving the values of these fields.

Also, how will I get the value of this field from request at server side  when the form will be submitted(using something like  request.getParameter("nameOfField") ).

Comment: can you tell us what language you are using?

Comment: I am using Java on server side.